# Passing out to_csv with specific delimiter, losing the header in the process

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello everyone as i was passing my df to csv, which has a header.Here a pic for proof.
[image]

Interesting enough as i was passing this csv, with a specific delimiter. Because it has a json response and it basically bugs out with comas. It returns with no header, does anyone know the probable reason?

Here is the code

```
# Prod is the df
my_numpy = prod.to_numpy()
np.savetxt(r'D:/Queries Claro/Dados_limpos.csv', my_numpy,fmt='%s', delimiter='|')
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using to_numpy() and save_txt() instead of to_csv() ?

Comment: It's a good idea to look at intermediate variables like `my_numpy`.  `savetxt` does allow you to provide a `header` line, but you can't get that from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy has no header names, so when you convert it from Pandas it loses the headers.
You can use instead:

```
prod.to_csv(r'D:/Queries Claro/Dados_limpos.csv', sep='|')
```